# Changing File to Upload With Variables

Tags: postman

I am able to create a test to send a file to my API as expected. This works.
[File Upload Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7z6y.png)

What I need to do now is change the file sent to my API based on data in the JSON data file used for collection runs. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: do you mean converting your file to JSON format ?

Comment: No, I am referring to the data file used for a collection run iteration. 

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files

Comment: from what I've experienced so far with the files that are used in collection runs, is that they can set variables in your request/body during the runs, but I don't think they can be sent to your API.